# Dynamic memory allocation and pointer non-char array type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I read this [C++ tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Chapters/Fundamentals), and in the pointers section there is a confusing example, exactly this:

```
double (*pVal2)[2]= new double[2][2]; //this will add 2x2 memory blocks to type double pointer
*(*(pVal2+0)+0) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+0)+1) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+0)+2) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+0)+3) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+0)+4) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+1)+0) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+1)+1) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+1)+2) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+1)+3) = 10;
*(*(pVal2+1)+4) = 10;
```

Is `int (*pVal)[2]` an array pointer? 
I do not understand why is it allocating memory for `double[2][2]` but the `*(*pVal2+1)+4)` goes to 4?

Comment: `int (*pVal)[2]` is a pointer to an array of 2 ints. Could you be more specific about "what is happening"? The tutorial looks quite poor BTW, it might be an idea to steer clear of it.

Comment: when dynamically allocating memory shouldn't it be allocated for double[2][5]?

Comment: @ner0x652 You mean `double[5][2]`? Either way, still wouldn't make the rest of the code valid...

Comment: @Barry it should be `double[2][5]` ; the innermost dimension goes from `0` to `1`

Comment: @ner0x652 you'd make life a lot easier for yourself just writing `pVal2[0][3]  = 10;` and so on

Comment: @M.M. Nope, outer. It's a pointer to an array of 2. The first index dereferences the pointer, the second index accesses the array.

Comment: @Barry `*(*(pVal2+0)+3) = 10;` means `pVal2[0][3]`. You got it right in your answer...

Comment: @M.M. that is true, but is unrelated to your other statement.

Comment: @Barry if the first index can range from 0-1, and the second index can range from 0-4, then the type should be `[2][5]`

Comment: @M.M Dude. Did you even try to compile what you're claiming? The correct syntax to allocate an array of 5 `double[2]`s is `double (*p)[2] = new double[5][2];` The `[2]` part in `double (*)[2]` is the *last* index.

Comment: @Barry that is an array of 5 elements, each of which are `double[2]`. Writing `pVal2[0][3]` would be an out-of-bounds access.  For OP's accessing code to work, the allocation needs to be `double (*pVal)[5] = new double[2][5];`

Comment: I think @Barry is right.

This is the output of clang++ when tried other version (new double[2][5], instead of double[5][2]):
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'double (*)[2]'
      with an rvalue of type 'double (*)[5]'
    double (*pVal)[2] = new double[2][5];

Anyway, thank you both for helping me understand that wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the spiral rule:

```
        +--------+
        | +---+  |
        | ^   |  |
double (*pVal2)[2];
 ^      ^     |  |
 |      +-----+  |
 +---------------+
```

`pVal2` is a pointer to an array of 2 `double`s. Or, simpler:

```
using T = double[2];
T *pVal2 = new T[2];
```

The rest of the code leads to undefined behavior as: `*(p + idx)` is equivalent to `p[idx]`, so `*(*(pVal2+1)+4)` is equivalent to `pVal2[1][4]`.But the type of `pVal2[1]` is `double[2]`, so there is no 5th element there...